# How to add radio buttons in Jenkins using groovy when building a job using "Build with parameters"?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to add `radio` buttons in Jenkins instead of `checkboxes` when running `Build with Parameters`. In my existing code, I am getting checkboxes. What changes should I make in my existing code to get the radio buttons. Below is my `groovy` code:

```
def call(Map config = [:]) {

    paramsList = []

    paramsList << booleanParam(name: 'deployToDev', defaultValue: false, description: 'Set to true to deploy to Dev K8s Environment')
    paramsList << booleanParam(name: 'deployToTest', defaultValue: false, description: 'Set to true to deploy to Test K8s Environment')
    paramsList << booleanParam(name: 'deployToStage', defaultValue: false, description: 'Set to true to deploy to Stage K8s Environment')
    properties([parameters(paramsList)])
}
```

Please find the below screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Are you using the `Active Choices` plugin?

Comment: Have you reviewed the [Jenkins Design Library](https://weekly.ci.jenkins.io/design-library/)? [Source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/design-library-plugin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that easily using the [Extended Choice Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter/) which has a built in support for all kinds of selection options including radio buttons.
You can use it as follows:

```groovy
def call(Map config = [:]) {

    paramsList = []

    // You can also set the default value using the 'defaultValue' option
    paramsList << extendedChoice(name: 'DeployTo', description: 'Select the environment to deploy to', type: 'PT_RADIO', value: 'Dev,Test,Stage', visibleItemCount: 5)

    properties([parameters(paramsList)])
}
```

The result will look like:
[image]

You can also use the [Active Choices](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) plugin, which is a bit more complicated but has more configuration options, it will also allow you to generate the values from a groovy script.
For example:

```groovy
properties([parameters(
   [[$class: 'ChoiceParameter', name: 'DeployTo', choiceType: 'PT_RADIO', description: 'Select the environment to deploy to', script: [$class: 'GroovyScript', script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, script: "return ['Dev','Test','Stage']"]]]]
)])
```

Comment: Extended Choice worked for me